# Detect UITapGestureRecognizer on UIView with transform

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, calayer

I’ve attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to my `UIView` which works as expected, however, as part of my user interface the view gets rotated when tapped the first time. Now, the same tap gesture is no longer fired when I try to tap on the view.

The transform is attached to the view’s layer.

How do I detect a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a view whose layer has a non `CATransform3DIdentity` transform?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am currently stuck on the same issue.

Comment: Honestly, I can't even remember the issue. Sorry!